# Unix shell scripting return code error with for loop

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am stuck in a script which has an if loop and a for loop, PFB the code in which I am getting the **syntax error at line : `((' unexpected**

```
 if [ $? = 0 ]; then
 for (( count=0; count<=number; count++ ))
    echo " statement"
done

else 
 echo " Else statement executed "
fi
```

Can anyone help me on this...?

Comment: I am new to unix shell script...what do you mean by if is not a loop...?

Comment: You wrote you have an `if`. There is no programming language where if is a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **done** and a **fi**

```
#!/bin/bash
number=4
if [ $? = 0 ]; then  
  for (( count=0; count<=number; count++ ))
  do
      echo "df"
  done
fi
```